# How to inject service dependencies from templates into controllers?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following `template.html`:

```
<html>
...
   <my-tab></my-tab>
...
</html>
```

Tag `<my-tab>` is represented by `tabTemplate.html` and managed by a `MyTab controller` with the following constructor:

```
constructor(
   private firstService: FirstServiceClass,
){
   this.doSomething();  // this fuction uses firstService
 }
```

`FirstServiceClass` - a custom class.

I have another tags like `<my-tab2>, <my-tab3>` etc. They are managed by `MyTab2, MyTab3` `controllers`.

The code of these controllers is almost the same, the difference between them is a parameter in a constructor.

I need to remove copypaste.

Is it possible to specify this parameter somehow?

Comment: I thinks it's best to refactor your code rather than making it complex by duplicating things

Comment: I try to do it but I am only getting started to learn angularJs. My templates are the same, my controllers have only one difference - this depency in a constructor. I thought it was possible to specify this depency as an attribute for example

Answer (score 1):

Use component bindings:

```
app.component("myTab", {
    bindings: {
        tab: "<"
    },
    controller: "myTabController",
    templateURL: "myTab.html"   
}
```

Usage:

```
<my-tab tab="0"></my-tab>
<my-tab tab="1"></my-tab>
```

```
class myTabController {
    constructor (firstService) {
        //...
    }
    $onInit() {
         console.log(this.tab);
         //...
    }
}
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based Architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture)

---

> for `tab="0"` it's needed to use `myTabController constructor(firstService)`. for `tab="1"` it's needed to use `myTabController constructor(secondService)`. Is it possible?

Use the `$injector` service to inject different services:

```
app.component("myTab", {
    bindings: {
        tab: "<",
        service: "@"
    },
    controller: "myTabController",
    templateURL: "myTab.html"   
}

class myTabController {
    constructor ($injector) {
        this.$injector = $injector;
    }
    $onInit() {            
        this.tabService = this.$injector.get(this.service);
        //...
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<my-tab tab="0" service="firstService"></my-tab>
<my-tab tab="1" service="secondService"></my-tab>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $injector Service API Reference - get](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector#get)

Comment: for tab="0" it's needed to use myTabController constructor(firstService). for tab="1" it's needed to use myTabController constructor(secondService). Is it possible?

Comment: As I understand firstService in service="firstService" is related to firstService.service.ts file. But how does angular undestand where it is situated? It could be src/js/users/ or src/js/words

Comment: While it is possible to choose services at runtime, I don't think it is a wise way to factor an app. All services need to be loaded into the injector before the app enters the run phase.

Comment: property "service" doesn't exist on type 'myTabController'

Comment: I have a firstController + firstTemplate, I have secondControler + secondTemplate. Than I see that these templates are equal. Controllers have fields and methods. They are almost the same. Only one of the fields has a different type - for example in firstContoller is situated conditionalTab: ConditionalUserTab and in secondController - conditionalTab: ConditionalItemTab.

Comment: Therefore I try to describe it using one template + one controller giving it different depencies(ConditionalUser and ConditionalItem for example). When I try to specify service visualStudioCode tells me that this field doesn't exist in my controller

Comment: Where Am I wrong? Is it a good idea providing a controller with different depencies?

Comment: I recommend that controllers be lightweight and only handle view logic. Business logic should be re-factored into a service. I don't see the need for multiple services all with the same signature.

Comment: Let's speak more specific. My controller provide a template with data to display as a table. It use ApiService which send a request to a server and get data. The first controller recieves UserData[] from UserApiService, the second receives ItemsData[] from ItemApiService

Comment: In a controller I just use apiService.getData() and manipulate it

Comment: And I need something like: when a user taps on <my-tab service="UserApiService"></my-tab> myTabController works with UserApiService, when a user taps on <my-tab service="ItemApiService"></my-tab> myTabController works with ItemApiService

Comment: Now I just have <my-tab> which works with MyTabController and <my-another-tab> which works with MyAnotherTabController

Answer (score 0):

you can create a directive for my-tab that would be better for binding new temple for this directive and use a model controller for logic.

Comment: Could you give a small example how it should look?

Answer (score 0):

////This html  will be inside parents controller

```
 <div class="tabClass hide">
       <my-tab></my-tab>
 </div>
```

////////////////////

```
'use strict';
angular.module('demoApp').directive('myTab', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: "~/MyTab.html",//Create a template for directive view named like MyTab
        restrict: "E",
        controller: function ($scope, $routeParams, $http, $filter, $modal ) {

        //essential code
        }

    };
});

//and finally add directive referance to index file or where you referances other js file in your project
```